# Heroku: My routes still pointing to localhost when deployed

Tags: mongodb, express, heroku, next.js, mongodb-atlas

I set up my `NODE_ENV` to production under `APP>Settings>Config Vars` on Heroku and set up a `mongo.json` file in my root directory:

```
{
    "development": {
        "host": "127.0.0.1:27017",
        "dbName": "hillfinder"
    },
    "production": {
        "PRODUCTION_DB_DSN": "mongodb+srv://***credentials***@hillfinder-qjxuo.mongodb.net/production?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
    }
}
```

But it's still pointing to localhost:

[image]

This is the my server/index.js:

```
const express = require('express');

require('dotenv').config();

const nextJS = require('next');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var auth = require('./lib/auth');
var cors = require('cors');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var HttpStatus = require('http-status-codes');
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 8016;

const { isBlockedPage, isInternalUrl } = require('next-server/dist/server/utils');

function NODE_ENVSetter(ENV) {
  var environment,
    environments = {
      production: () => {
        environment = process.env.PRODUCTION_DB_DSN;
        console.log(`We are currently in the production environment: ${environment}`);
        return environment;
      },
      test: () => {
        environment = process.env.TEST_DB_DSN;
        console.log(`We are currently in the test environment: ${environment}`);
        return environment;
      },
      default: () => {
        environment = process.env.DEVELOPMENT_DB_DSN;
        console.log(`We are currently in the development environment: ${environment}`);
        return environment;
      }
    };
  (environments[ENV] || environments['default'])();

  return environment;
}

var db = NODE_ENVSetter('production');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
  // Set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // Log error
  console.error(err.stack);

  // Render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);

  // Default error message by HTTP code
  res.render('error', {
    title: HttpStatus.getStatusText(err.status),
    message: HttpStatus.getStatusText(err.status)
  });
}

async function start() {
  const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
  const app = nextJS({ dev });
  const server = express();
  await app
    .prepare()
    .then(() => {
      mongoose.connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true });
      mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

      mongoose.connection
        .on('connected', () => {
          console.log(`Mongoose connection open on ${db}`);
        })
        .on('error', err => {
          console.log(`Connection error: ${err.message}`);
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });

  server.set('view engine', 'html');

  server.use('/uploads', express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'));
  server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: false }));
  server.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
  server.use(morgan('dev'));

  server.use(cookieParser());

  server.use(
    session({
      secret: 'very secret 12345',
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
    })
  );

  server.use(auth.initialize);
  server.use(auth.session);
  server.use(auth.setUser);
  console.log('auth.setUser ', auth.setUser);

  server.use(cors());
  server.use('/users', require('./users'));
  server.use('/images', require('./images'));

  // Redirect all requests to main entrypoint pages/index.js
  server.get('/*', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {

      const pathName = req.originalUrl;
      if (isInternalUrl(req.url)) {
        return app.handleRequest(req, res, req.originalUrl);
      }

      if (isBlockedPage(pathName)) {
        return app.render404(req, res, req.originalUrl);
      }

      req.locals = {};
      req.locals.context = {};
      const html = await app.renderToHTML(req, res, '/', {});

      // Handle client redirects
      const context = req.locals.context;
      if (context.url) {
        return res.redirect(context.url);
      }

      // Handle client response statuses
      if (context.status) {
        return res.status(context.status).send();
      }

      // Request was ended by the user
      if (html === null) {
        return;
      }

      app.sendHTML(req, res, html);
    } catch (e) {
      next(e);
    }
  });

  // error handler
  server.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    // set locals, only providing error in development
    res.locals.errorStatus = err.status;
    res.locals.errorMessage = err.message;
    res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

    // render the error page

    console.log('err.status ', err.status);
    res.status(err.status).send(err.message);
  });

  server.listen(PORT, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> Ready and listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
  });
}

start();
```

How would I fix that so I can log on to MongoDB atlas?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `server.use('/uploads', express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'));` this is pointing to static files in which `localhost` is referenced.

Comment: Pretty sure `__dirname` resolves to what every your root is... Thanks though!